# ExtJS 4.2: Reset Proxy Url on Second Call

Tags: extjs, proxy

How do you reset a proxy url before calling it again? I currently have this:

```
var sUrl = oStore.getProxy().url;
var internalId = oMe.getEcommIdField().html;
sUrl = sUrl.replace('/' + internalId, '');
sUrl = sUrl.replace('/activities', '');
sUrl = sUrl + '/' + oMe.getEcommIdField().html + '/activities/';
oStore.getProxy().url = sUrl;
oStore.load({
  callback: function() {
    oMask.hide();
    // console.log('sUrl',sUrl);
  }
});
```

On first load, this correctly calls the correct url: `base_url/{internalId}/activities`

But when I try to make a call again, it retains the previous value and appends with the new one, such as: `base_url/{internalId}//{internalId}/activities`

How do I properly reuse the proxy url to assign a newly loaded one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `setUrl` function to proxy:

```
Ext.define('Path.store.YourStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Path.model.YourModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        urlTpl: 'base_url/{internalId}/activities',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'activities',
        },
        setUrl: function (internalId) {
            this.url = this.urlTpl.replace('{internalId}', internalId);
        }
    }
});
```

and then use it like

```
var internalId = oMe.getEcommIdField().html;
oStore.getProxy().setUrl(internalId); // now url = base_url/current_internalId/activities
oStore.load({
  callback: function() {
  }
});
```

Or you can change whole url in proxy :

```
  setUrl: function (url) {
            this.url = url;
        }


var internalId = oMe.getEcommIdField().html;
oStore.getProxy().setUrl('new_url/' + internalId + '/path'); // now url = new_url/current_internalId/path
oStore.load({
  callback: function() {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way will be to make use of [beforeload](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-beforeload)/[beforesync](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-beforesync) event of store. Like this:

listeners: {

```
beforeload: function( store, operation, eOpts ){

    // Checks if you have to look for some condition ..
    if(typeof param != "undefined" )
    {
        var proxy = store .getProxy();
        proxy.url = "my url";
        proxy.extraParams = "my parameters";
        store.setProxy(proxy);
    }
    else
        console.log("Job Not Completed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you were doing is right. The problem is because of this code.

```
sUrl = sUrl + '/' + oMe.getEcommIdField().html + '/activities/';
/*
 * after this sUrl = 'base_url/{internalId}//{internalId}/activities/'
 */
```

Just make sure the url is correct before assign it to the store. The common way to assign the new url to store is what you were using.

```
store.getProxy().url = newUrl;
store.load();
```